# Is there an equivalent to map::key_type for Collections::Generic::Dictionary in C++/CLI?

Tags: .net, templates, c++-cli

In a C++ templated function with the std::map type as template I can use T::key_type and T::value_type to create keys and values.
Is there an equivalent in C++/CLI if T is a Collections::Generic::Dictionary?

I couldn't see anything on [the MSDN Dictionary page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I want to do something along the lines of:

```
   template<typename T> // T is a Collections::Generic::Dictionary
   T^ Copy(T^ src)
   {
      T^ dst;
      Threading::Monitor::Enter(src);
      try
      {
         dst = gcnew T(src);
         for each (T::key_type^ key in src->Keys) // no such type!
         {
            T::value_type^ srcValue = dynamic_cast<T::value_type^>(src[key]); // no such type!
            if (srcValue)
            {
               T::value_type^ copiedValue = gcnew T::value_type(/*some values common to my value types here*/); // no such type!
               copiedValue->Clone(*srcValue);
               dst->Add(key, copiedValue);
            }
         }
      }
      finally
      {
         Threading::Monitor::Exit(src);
      }
      return dst;
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

There may be a better way, but: As of Visual Studio 2010, the C++/CLI compiler supports many of the new C++1x features including `decltype` and `auto`. Using these, you can do things like:

```
typedef decltype(src->Keys->GetEnumerator().Current) key_type;
typedef decltype(src->Values->GetEnumerator().Current) value_type;
```

Or

```
auto srcValue = src[key];
```

---

For older versions, you might try partial template specialization:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;

ref class Val
{
public:
    void CloneFrom(Val^) {}
};

template<typename D> struct dictionary_traits;
template<typename K, typename V> struct dictionary_traits<Collections::Generic::Dictionary<K, V>>
{
    typedef K key_type;
    typedef V value_type;
};

template<typename T> struct strip_managed;
template<typename T> struct strip_managed<T^>
{
    typedef T type;
};

template<typename T> // T is a Collections::Generic::Dictionary
T^ Copy(T^ src)
{
    typedef typename dictionary_traits<T>::key_type key_type;
    typedef typename dictionary_traits<T>::value_type value_type;

    T^ dst;
    Threading::Monitor::Enter(src);
    try
    {
        dst = gcnew T(src);
        for each (key_type key in src->Keys)
        {
            value_type srcValue = src[key];
            if (srcValue)
            {
                value_type copiedValue = gcnew typename strip_managed<value_type>::type();
                copiedValue->CloneFrom(srcValue);
                dst->Add(key, copiedValue);
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Threading::Monitor::Exit(src);
    }
    return dst;
}

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    auto dict = gcnew Collections::Generic::Dictionary<Object^, Val^>();
    Copy(dict);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that is interesting but I think we currently need to keep compatibility with VS2008

Comment: I have added a second potential solution. I do not have a copy of VS2008 to test it though.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary is a generic class, not a template.  When in Rome, act like a Roman and write a generic method:

```
ref class Example {
public:
    generic<typename K, typename V>
    Dictionary<K, V>^ Copy(IDictionary<K, V>^ src) {
        auto cpy = gcnew Dictionary <K, V> ;
        for each (K key in src->Keys) cpy->Add(key, src[key]);
        return cpy;
    }
};
```

Do note that this creates a shallow copy of the values in the dictionary.  Which is fine if V is a value-type, perhaps not so fine if it is a reference type.  Although it is *much* less necessary in .NET thanks to the garbage collector.  If required, then do keep in mind that there is no general way to deep-copy an object of a reference type, unless you explicitly implement it yourself.  This requires, say, an IDeepClone interface, implemented by the V type.  For example:

```
generic<typename T>
interface class IDeepClone {
    T Copy();
};
```

You tell the compiler about it with a constraint using the *where* keyword:

```
ref class Example {
public:
    generic<typename K, typename V> 
    where V:IDeepClone<V>
    Dictionary<K, V>^ Copy(IDictionary<K, V>^ src) {
        auto cpy = gcnew Dictionary <K, V> ;
        for each (K key in src->Keys) cpy->Add(key, src[key]->Copy());
        return cpy;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks this looks good. I did originally try generics but I got error C3227: 'T' : cannot use 'gcnew' to allocate a generic type to create the values so I used templates. I will try again based on your example.

Comment: Well, that requires another *where* clause, one that promises that the type has a parameterless constructor.  But yes, this code should be good as-is afaict.